# Pick keys of a type entered dynamically

Tags: typescript

I have a module exported like this.

`index.ts`

```
export { A } from './A';
export { B } from './B';
export { C } from './C';
```

I'm importing them like this.

```
import * as X from 'index.ts'
```

In the imported file I'm setting up an interface like this.

```
type T = keyof typeof X;

interface Interface extends Record<string, unknown> {
  version: number;
  manager: T;
  methodName: keyof typeof X[T];
}
```

All of A, B, C are objects exported from each. Like this.

```
export const A = {
  func1,
  func2,
};

export const B = {
  func1,
  func2,
};

export const C = {
  func1,
  func2,
};
```

What I'm trying to attempt is when creating an object from interface `Interface` to help the developers easily pick the `manager` and `methodName`. The manager names are fine. But I'm struggling with given the manager name to list the functions available in it because the type of `methodName` is `never`.

If I remove `keyof` from `methodName: keyof typeof X[T];` then I see the typeof the manager picked correctly but this is not what I want to achieve

My exact usage is, when a develop writes;

```
logManagerUsage({
      manager: 'A',
      methodName: 'func1',
    }),
```

to have only the logs related to that recorded. I'm trying to achieve this so that in the future with more managers and functions added I will not have to actively maintain the interface for this function.

Comment: [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is needed. I'm unable to reproduce your problem with the code provided.

Comment: Here you go `shorturl.at/kmEOT`